# IPTables - 2 Nics - Private - Public - Private route

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nat

I have a CentOS 7 with 2 NICs (`enp1s0` - private LAN 192.168.0.0/24 and `enp0s29u1u1` - public) that I use as a gateway / router via `iptables`. All PCs on the private LAN connect to the internet via the gateway. Also, I have some services on the private LAN that I can access from anywhere, I use port forwarding for these services. For example, I have a web server on 192.168.0.77 port 80 that I can also access from anywhere via the public IP given by my ISP, the rule to to this is:

```
-A PREROUTING -d my_public_ip -i enp0s29u1u1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.77:80
```

The problem with this rule is that I can access the site: [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) **when I am not at my local network**, but when I am using the local network, it only works through the private IP: 192.168.0.77.

The complete rule I have right now is:

[image]

What other rule should I add to be able to access the web server from my local network using the public IP?

Comment: Do not post images of text, please.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Thanks. Will not do it any more.

Comment: It seems that your `FORWARD` chain policy is set to accept so that looks ok. I think you are missing the `MASQUERADE` target of the `POSTROUTING` chain. i.e:  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s29u1u1 -j MASQUERADE`.

Comment: I have that.-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp0s29u1u1 -j SNAT --to-source my_public_ip.

Comment: It's a classic [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) problem.

Comment: Do you mean with www.mysite.com the public address given by your ISP? Or put it the other way: do you want to access the server at 192.168.0.77 from your local network but use the public IP?

Answer (score 0):

You have bound the port forwarding rule to the external interface
but your traffic from the local network arrives at the internal interface of the gateway. Therefore this traffic is not forwarded to the web server.

Simply making the port forwarding available for all interfaces is just a part of the solution.
Then your connection attempts to the external address would be forwarded to the web server
but the return packets from the web server would go directly to your client in the lan and the addresses would not match (the client sends to the external address and gets an answer from the internal address).

To make the web server accessible with the external address from within the local network,
you have to:

- make port forwarding available for all interfaces
- masquerade traffic destined for the web server and coming from the local network to the local address of the gateway.